# How to use arithmetic minus in mysql between two select?

Tags: mysql

```
select player.ActionTime from question_log log inner join player_question player 
where log.ActionType='96'

select player.ActionTime from question_log log inner join player_question player 
where log.ActionType='97'
```

How to make that happen in mysql syntax? Select Actiontime of which ActionType is 96 minus the other of which is 97.  Arithmetic minus.

Comment: what do you mean with minus ? arithmatic operation ? please give sample in your post

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT t96.ActionTime - t97.ActionTime
FROM
(
    select player.ActionTime 
    from question_log log 
    inner join player_question player 
    where log.ActionType='96'
) t96
CROSS JOIN
(
    select player.ActionTime 
    from question_log log 
    inner join player_question player 
    where log.ActionType='97'
) t97
```

Note, there does not seem to be anything related between your two queries, so I can only suggest a `CROSS JOIN` (Cartesian product). If you have more than one row of log.ActionType = '96' or log.ActionType = '97' you are going to have many result rows.

Answer (score 0):

Use subquery :

```
SELECT player.ActionTime - (SELECT player.ActionTime from question_log log inner join     player_question player where log.ActionType='97' LIMIT 1)
from question_log log inner join player_question player where log.ActionType='96'
```